# Windows 10 PC display is out of range on boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, display, resolution

I've been attempting to set up backlight strobing for my monitor on my Windows 10 desktop PC. The instructions told me to reboot at some point, so I did. Now, Windows boots, but I cannot see anything on the screen. I cannot plug in another monitor

Normally on other versions of Windows I would boot into Safe Mode and try again, but with Windows 10 this seems to be impossible. Pressing F8 before booting does not work. I also tried to use a recovery USB disk, but there doesn't seem to be an option for booting into safe mode. I tried following the instructions here: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/22455-f8-advanced-boot-options-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html to enable the boot menu, but that doesn't work and I get an error that says that the boot configuration data store could not be found. I think I need to specify a drive ID, but I'm not sure how. The help text doesn't seem to explain it.

I also tried:

- Disabling UEFI and fast boot settings from the BIOS.... though I don't think it was enabled in the first place...
- Startup repair from the USB recovery drive. It doesn't see anything wrong.
- Force shutting down the PC more than 3 times. That doesn't force the boot menu to appear.

Other websites and forums seem to suggest that the only way out of this is to reformat. I refuse to consider that a solution, there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, althought by chance mostly

While Windows is booting (i.e. during the splash screen), reset the computer. Don't force power off, press the reset button. There's a difference it seems

You should get a screen asking if you want to get advanced repair options. Use a keyboard and select that.

Go to Troubleshoot, then Advanced Options, then Startup Settings, then press restart, and your computer should restart

When it restart, you should see a screen with different options, much like the old boot menus. You can select low resolution mode, but that didn't work for me. Safe mode is still there, thankfully. I was finally able to get it to work!